# php / mysql, auto refresh when the database changes

Tags: php, mysql, events, triggers

I want to automatically refresh the data, once the tables in my database change (After adding, updating or deleting records).

I use php pdo / mysql with angularjs

I know I have to use a trigger, but how do I link my trigger to my PHP file?

For delphi / firebird: There is a libririe for that (zeoLibs) with the system of events. is there an equivalent liberty?

thank you in advance

Comment: You can't have an event in MySQL trigger code in PHP.

Comment: Do you want to refresh your website when data changes? This is not easily possible, as there is no way to communicate changes from the MySQL server to your browser directly

Comment: yes i  want to refresh my website when data changes, like with ajax in chat application.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find information about `WebSocket` and try to work with it. I hope this is the solution for you.
It works perfect with angularjs two-way data binding.

Comment: I'm going to do my research on that

Comment: @Daya If this is the anwser and solution for you don't forget to mark it as right.